# How to prevent user from closing system dialog without clicking an option in android

Tags: android, kotlin

I have the following intent that calls the system screen to choose a midia.

```
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI)
startActivityForResult(intent, Code.GALLERY);
```

[image: android phone example]

If the user clicks outside the system dialog, or the back button or swipes it down, the window closes.

Is there a way to prevent the user from closing it in all those ways?

**I mean, is there a way to ONLY close this dialog IF the user selects an option from the list?**

Comment: I don't think there is a way . you need to create your own custom Dialog for it . Also after you disable those options how will user suppose to close the dialog anyway ?

Comment: I found another way to control it, I used the lifecycle methods to control the visibility of the screen I had before this one.